# Como hacer un trigger en MySql que actulize la fecha despues de un update

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito hacer un trigger que haga lo siguiente:
Despues de que se actualiza un registro, tambien el trigger actualize el campo "ultimaActualizacion" colocando la fecha actual del pc.
Estos son mis campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes pone tu código, lo que has intentado porque parece que esto es toma y hacerme la tarea.

Comment: Si usaras DATETIME no necesitarías el disparador, define como  `ultimaActualizacion DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y así la fecha se actualizará automáticamente si cambia cualquiera de las otras columnas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconozco que aun me queda por aprender en este tema, pero a mi lo unico que se me ocurre es crear 5 triggers en vez de 1. No conozco la forma de hacer esa accion dentro de uno solo. Dependiendo del campo que actualices, se ejecutara un trigger u otro.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_ultimaActualizacion AFTER UPDATE ON "tabla" FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

     UPDATE "tabla" 
     SET ultimaActualizacion=CURDATE() 
     WHERE nom_reportes=NEW.nomreportes;

END //
```

En "tabla" deberás poner el nombre de tu tabla, y deberas crear en base a este modelo 4 más. Cambiarías solo la condicion del where. Donde ahora tienes nom_reportes pondrías los otros campos de la tabla.
Espero que te ayude !!

Comment: acepta la edición porque tu código no se entendía bien